# Index Pagination when using two view models?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, pagination

Before I had only one view model but now I have made one that contains two:

```
public class ApplicationTwoViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Project> Model1 { get; set; }
        public Application Model2 { get; set; }
    }
```

The pagination worked before, but now that I have to deal with Model1 and Model2, it no longer works and had a hard time fixing it.
Here is what I have tried so far:

```
 public class ProjectsController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: Projects
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Index(string SortOrder, string SortBy, string Page)
        {
            ViewBag.SortOrder = SortOrder;
            ViewBag.SortBy = SortBy;
            var projects = db.Projects.ToList();
            var model = new ApplicationTwoViewModel
            {
                Model1 = new List<Project>(projects),
                Model2 = new Application
                {
                    //hard coded, needs change
                    UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                    ProjectId = 11,
                    CoverLetter = "asdf",
                    ApplicationId = 23,
                }
            };

            switch (SortBy)
            {
                case "Title":
                 switch (SortOrder)
                    {
                        case "Asc":
                            projects = projects.OrderBy(x => x.Title).ToList();
                            break;
                        case "Desc":
                            projects = projects.OrderByDescending(x => x.Title).ToList();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

                case "ApplicationDeadline":
                    switch (SortOrder)
                    {
                        case "Asc":
                            projects = projects.OrderBy(x => x.ApplicationDeadline).ToList();
                            break;
                        case "Desc":
                            projects = projects.OrderByDescending(x => x.ApplicationDeadline).ToList();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

                case "Duration":
                    switch (SortOrder)
                    {
                        case "Asc":
                            projects = projects.OrderBy(x => x.Duration).ToList();
                            break;
                        case "Desc":
                            projects = projects.OrderByDescending(x => x.Duration).ToList();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case "HourlyRate":
                    switch (SortOrder)
                    {
                        case "Asc":
                            projects = projects.OrderBy(x => x.HourlyRate).ToList();
                            break;
                        case "Desc":
                            projects = projects.OrderByDescending(x => x.HourlyRate).ToList();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case "TotalProjectCost":
                    switch (SortOrder)
                    {
                        case "Asc":
                            projects = projects.OrderBy(x => x.TotalProjectCost).ToList();
                            break;
                        case "Desc":
                            projects = projects.OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalProjectCost).ToList();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case "City":
                    switch (SortOrder)
                    {
                        case "Asc":
                            projects = projects.OrderBy(x => x.City).ToList();
                            break;
                        case "Desc":
                            projects = projects.OrderByDescending(x => x.City).ToList();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case "RequiredPresencePercent":
                    switch (SortOrder)
                    {
                        case "Asc":
                            projects = projects.OrderBy(x => x.RequiredPresencePercent).ToList();
                            break;
                        case "Desc":
                            projects = projects.OrderByDescending(x => x.RequiredPresencePercent).ToList();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case "Language":
                    switch (SortOrder)
                    {
                        case "Asc":
                            projects = projects.OrderBy(x => x.Language).ToList();
                            break;
                        case "Desc":
                            projects = projects.OrderByDescending(x => x.Language).ToList();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case "RequiredSkills":
                    switch (SortOrder)
                    {
                        case "Asc":
                            projects = projects.OrderBy(x => x.RequiredSkills).ToList();
                            break;
                        case "Desc":
                            projects = projects.OrderByDescending(x => x.RequiredSkills).ToList();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    projects = projects.OrderBy(x => x.Title).ToList();
                    break;
            }



            ViewBag.TotalPages = Math.Ceiling(db.Projects.ToList().Count()/10.0);

        int page = int.Parse(Page == null ? "1" : Page);
        ViewBag.Page = page;
        // before it was projects = projects.Skip ....
        model.Model1 = model.Model1.Skip((page - 1) * 10).Take(10).ToList();
        return View(model);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sorting your projects but don't set to your model that you pass to View add this line:

```
// before it was projects = projects.Skip ....
model.Model1 = projects; // <-- this line
model.Model1 = model.Model1.Skip((page - 1) * 10).Take(10).ToList();
return View(model);
```